# landscape layout, no rotation

Tags: android, kotlin

I created new project in Android Studio, then I generated layout for landscape and edit it a bit. But when I rotate virtual device, layout don't change. Why?

[image: VirtualDeviceImage]

Comment: First make sure your emulator is not orientation locked. Drag down from the top to see device quick settings and verify "auto-rotate" is enabled.

Comment: Ohhh god, yes, it was locked.. Thank you!